# Run process in Background iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, background-process, uiapplication

I've a question:

I'm writing an application. This application have many function.
One of this functions need to works also in background.
This function don't needs download data or use a standard process (i've found many page with example to explain how i can download a file in background or how i can use the notification in background), but i need only understand how to don't stop the running process work when i use the telephone with other app or i lock the mobile to sleep.

I've try to use the UIBackgroundFetchResult but i don't understand how this process works in a storyboard view.

How i can don't stop the process in a view when it's running, and i change application?
Thz

Comment: What do you want to do? In general apps are not allowed to continue to run in the background. There are just a few cases that do work. For instance navigation apps or music apps.

Comment: You have two problems: How to continue running in the background, and how to convince Apple to let your app go on the App Store. Since running in the background eats up batteries quickly, the second task will be the harder one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on Background permissions in your project settings? You need to enable that to have your app continue running in the background, and even then there are limits on what the system will let you do (like if a request to a URL takes too long).